# Getting number of arguments error with scikit RFE

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I came across this error. I think it is an issue with my local setup.

```
# Importing RFE and LinearRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Running RFE with the output number of the variable equal to 10
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

rfe = RFE(lm, 10)             # running RFE
rfe = rfe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the following error when I run the cell on jupyter

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3420/241754350.py in <module>
      3 lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
      4 
----> 5 rfe = RFE(lm, 10)             # running RFE
      6 rfe = rfe.fit(X_train, y_train)

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The above code seems to be working for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the `__init__` method of RFE class (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py#L176), you can only pass two positional arguments (`self` and `estimator`).

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> Parameters after “`*`” or “`*identifier`” are keyword-only parameters and may only be passed used keyword arguments.

In your case, you should type:

```
rfe = RFE(lm, n_features_to_select=10)
```